# I am trying to use Tensorflow as an environment of Anaconda but am getting some errors

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, virtualenv

So when I activate my virtual environment that i created through anaconda, the following line:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

works fine. However, the following line gives an error:

```
>>> from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.examples'
```

Any clues as to how I should fix this?

Comment: Do you have a folder named `examples` with `__init__.py` under `tensorflow`?

Comment: I just followed the steps to install tensorflow, so I have not created any additional paths. How do I do this?

Comment: Then check if you have that folder and file in it, and let me know :)

Comment: No I don't have an  examples folder. How do I make one?

Comment: Then something probably haven't been installed correctly, because if you don't have that folder you can't get `input_data` `import`ed. I don't think there's more that I can help you, other than try and reinstalling and follow that guide step by step.

Comment: I've been able to use this before without having that folder. It's just now that it is acting weird, after I switched to the anaconda virtual environment.

Comment: @codemonkey What is your tensorflow version? [1.7.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases) deprecates `tf.contrib.learn` and removes some deprecated modules/datasets in `tf.contrib.data`. I'm wondering if that's the reason.

Comment: My version is 1.0

Comment: @codemonkey It sounds like you've used tensorflow without anaconda. Is that possible you end up with multiple tensorflows on your machine and that leads to this problem?

Comment: Yeah, I think that is the problem. Thank you!